# Linked List of sorted names C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have a problem with a linked list that I had to create.
The program should take in user input of names and then put them into a linked list. This list should be sorted alphabetically, so when a new node is added it should go to the right position.

My code looks like this for now:

```
struct node
{
  string info;
  node *next;
};

class Passenger
{
 private:
  node* pname;
 public:
  void insert(string);
  Passenger();
};//closes Passenger class 

Passenger::Passenger()
{
  pname = new node;
  pname -> info = "ABC";
  pname -> next = NULL;
}

void Passenger::insert(string name)
{
  node *temp, *p, *s;
  p = pname;
  s = pname;
  temp = new node;
  temp->info = name;
  if(p-> info == "ABC")  //new pname linked list, put temp at the front                                                                         
    {
      p->info = name;
      p->next = NULL;
    }

  //if there is already one in the list                                                                                                         
  while(s != NULL)
    {
      cout<<"inside while loop"<<endl;

      //if new node goes to left                                                                                                                
      if(temp->info < s->info)
        {
          temp->next = p;
          pname = temp;
        }//closes if              
      if(temp->info > s->info)
        {
          if(p->next != NULL)
            {
              s = s->next;
              if(s->next == NULL)
                s->next = temp;
            }//closes if                                                                                                                        
        }//closes if                                                                                                                            
      p = p->next;
      s = s->next;
    }//closes while
```

I really don't know how to change it that it works. I got it done when there was one node in the list and then add a second one. But if there are 2 nodes already there I don't know how to sort a third or fourth node in.

Dave

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/26839/linked-list-sorting-algorithm - this may be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, representing an empty list with a sentinel node containing "ABC" is ridiculous.  What if someone wants to store a list that starts with that?  Using a NULL pointer to represent an empty list is a near-universal convention.

Also, the nodes don't have to be a different type.  The list class itself can be a node.  So an instance of the class is just an instance of the first node, with a pointer to the rest of the list.  Or, to better handle empty lists, you can have a container class that keeps pointers to the head (and optionally tail, for fast tail-insertion).  Implementation helper-functions can be member functions of the nodes, not the container class, if you like, so you can call them on any sub-list.

---

When I was learning linked-lists, I often found it helped to draw circles for nodes and arrows for pointers on a piece of paper, like in the data structures textbook.  Then you don't have to keep as much up-in-the-air mentally while you think through the process and any special-cases (beginning or end of the list).

---

You could break the problem down into two parts: the search, and the insert.

Your search function should return a pointer to the node before the insert position.  i.e. the last node with a string that compares less than the one you're inserting.  Your loop in that function then needs to either look ahead to the next element, or keep a `prev` pointer.  Either way, you need to get back to the node *before* the one that stops the loop.

Inserting after a node is pretty easy.  There's a special case when you need to insert a new head of the list, because there's no node to modify to point to the new current list.  But you don't need to care whether the node you're inserting after was the end of the list or not.

You can reduce the amount of special cases [by using a "dummy" node pointing to the actual first element](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/104949/50567).  This trick might not work for a comparison-based insert, compared to an InsertNth.  My [answer on that question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/104985/50567) breaks things down into find and insert, and is written in a C-like style even though that was a Java code-review question.  See the `InsertAfter` and `InsertBefore` methods.